# jQuery gives $ is undefined while refreshing the page?(asp .net MVC2)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Jquery gives $ is undefined while refreshing the page why??
Scripts included

```
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#button").click(function () {
               $("#button").hide();
           });
       });
</script>`
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery itself or just the jQuery UI?

Comment: What happens if you don't import two different versions of jQuery?

Comment: @dotweb I've edited the question to fix the code, all of the script tags should now be visible.

Comment: I suggest you provide a demo page.

Comment: I partially Fixed it. Problem was in my virtual path(given by me). I just removed it and now no issue left.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You only include jQueryUI (and only the CSS of it) not the original jQuery.

jQuery UI is just a Plugin/Addon to jQuery.</strike>

You are including two different Versions of jQuery, this might cause conflicts.

Comment: That appeared to be the case because the formatting in the question was wrong, there should have been a number of `<script>` tags to import the jQuery and jQuery UI js files.

Comment: No mike including two version is not the issue with me atleast.

Comment: I don't think this could cause a conflict. The last loaded jQuery version will just overwrite `$` and `jQuery`. It's unnecessary though.

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong with the way you are using relative paths for the Javascript files.

Replace your

`src="..."` with

`src="<% Url.Content("~/Scripts/x.js")%>"`

as in Nicholas's answer.  Make sure that ~/Scripts is the correct relative path to your Scripts folder! 'x' is the name of your Javascript file.

Comment: haha, I had gotten up to get a drink and then wrote the comment.  There were no comments when I first got to the post :P

Comment: If you want to ask a question or for additional details, it should be a comment rather than an answer (since it doesn't answer the question).

Comment: ok, thanks for that info.  I only joined tonight; I'll be more careful in the future!

Comment: Hi Kannas, is it possible to mark my new answer correct?  I had mentioned the possible issues with the relative paths as well as a generic fix.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Include at the top or bottom of your page</strike>

```
<script src="<% Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can drag this from your scripts folder within visual studio

**Edit: from your updated question it seems you have already carried this out**

It could be that on page refresh the inline script is being executed before your jquery has a chance to load.

Try moving your jquery references to the bottom of your html, just above the closing body tag.